# How do I get the cell value from a datagridview using row index and column index in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview **dgvList**.. Then I want to get the cell value of a particular row and column, without using the selectedRows property.

ie:

```
myvalue = dgvList[2nd row][1st column];
```

Comment: dvgList.Rows[yourRow].Cells[yourCell] ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try This

```
myvalue =dgvList.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dgvList.Rows[INDEX].Cells[INDEX].Value
```

Comment: its also missing in your question

Answer (score 1):

```
dgvList[colIndex, rowIndex].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvalue =dgvList.Rows[columnindex, rowindex].Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

how to display database value in dvg in dgv cell leave event

```
str = "select pprice from product_tbl2 where name='" & Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString() & "'"
                cmd.CommandText = str
                MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
                cmd.Connection = cn
                da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, cn)
                dt = New DataTable()
                da.Fill(dt)
                dvg.currentrows.cell(3) = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
```