# Get all columns (items) from DataGrid by row index

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I got a `DataGrid` row index and I now I'd like to get the value of a column `id` in that row. I tried numerous things not worth mentioning and Google doesn't come up with an answer either.

Any ideas?

Edit: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045468/ho-do-i-get-the-cell-value-from-a-datagridview-using-row-index-and-column-index), however, the properties used aren't available in WPF but only WinForms.

Comment: What are you working on? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: As stated in the tags, WPF.

Comment: Aren't you using data binding? If you use a ItemsSource on the datagrid, each row will be found to the corresponding row in the bound list of data.

Answer (score 1):

You could access an item in the `Items` collection of the `DataGrid` by index and then cast it to your type, e.g.:

```
int index = 0; //<-- your index
YourClass dataObject = dataGrid.Items[index] as YourClass;
int id = dataObject.Id;
```