# c# - how to select value from datagridview to textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

i am a beginner in c # and i have the task of such a project.
the first value is column ..this, textbox 1
the second value is row..this, textbox 2
final result..this, textbox 3

DATAGRIDVIEW will not be visible.

`DATAGRIDVIEW.VISIBLE = FALSE;`

so I can't click on datagridview

how should I do it ?
my codes were not functional, thank you very much for the answer.
Sorry for my bad english.

[image]

not code

Comment: man, please, show some code... we are not gods to know how it looks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the cell value from a datagridview using row index and column index in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045468/how-do-i-get-the-cell-value-from-a-datagridview-using-row-index-and-column-index)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataGridViewCell.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCell_Value) Property to retrieve the value stored in a particular cell. 
Use something like this in event handler

```
NameOfDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my code
the selected column does not work, it does not add it to a specific row that is my textbox1, but scrolls to the column and next row.
I want for example
textbox 1 = 0.3 value from datagridview
textbox 2 = 1 value from datagridview
textbox 3 is my result
anyone have any attacks? thank you for your answers

```
  for (int c = 0; c < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; c++)
        {
            int x = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[c].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
            {

                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[c].Cells[0];
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Selected = true;

            }

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[x].Value.ToString() == textBox2.Text)

            {
                dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowindex].Cells[x].Value.ToString();

            }
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[rowindex].Value.ToString();

        }
```